# elementor custome widget code for responsive range?

Tags: elementor

I am building an Elementor widget in which I want to have different range for a slider based on the device.
So when designing for Desktop the Slider will go from -100 to 100, and when designing for Mobile the same slider will have a range of -500 to 500.

I currently have this code:

```
    $this->add_responsive_control(
                'Obj-PosX',
                [
                  'label' => __( 'Horizontal change', 'plugin-domain' ),
                  'type' => Controls_Manager::SLIDER,                               
                  'range' => [                  
                    '%' => [                        
                        'desktop' => [
                            'min' => -100,
                            'max' => 100,                       
                        ],
                        'tablet' => [
                            'min' => -100,
                            'max' => 100,                       
                        ],
                        'mobile' => [
                            'min' => -500,
                            'max' => 500,                       
                        ],                      
                      ],                    
                  ],
                  'default' => [
                    'unit' => '%',
                    'size' => 0,
                  ],
                  'selectors' => [                  
                    '{{WRAPPER}} .theImage' => 'left: {{SIZE}}{{UNIT}};',
                  ],
                ]
              );
```

However when I run it, and go into the specific controller in the Elementor editor - I get an empty screen in the editor :(.

Maybe someone has a suggestion???

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old but I'd like to answer to this question
unfortunately elementor does not have something like this the way you can do this is like this :

```
$this->add_responsive_control(
  'Obj-PosX',
  [
    'label' => __( 'Horizontal change', 'plugin-domain' ),
    'type' => Controls_Manager::SLIDER,                
    'devices' => ['desktop'],               
    'range' => [                  
      'min' => -100, 
      'max' => 100,  
      'step'=> 1 ,                      
    ],                    

    'default' => [
      'unit' => '%',
      'size' => 0,
    ],
    'selectors' => [                  
      '{{WRAPPER}} .theImage' => 'left: {{SIZE}}{{UNIT}};',
    ],
  ]
);

$this->add_responsive_control(
  'Obj-PosXMobile',
  [
    'label' => __( 'Horizontal change', 'plugin-domain' ),
    'type' => Controls_Manager::SLIDER,                
    'devices' => ['mobile'],               
    'range' => [                  
      'min' => -500, 
      'max' => 500,  
      'step'=> 1 ,                      
    ],                    

    'default' => [
      'unit' => '%',
      'size' => 0,
    ],
    'selectors' => [                  
      '(mobile){{WRAPPER}} .theImage' => 'left: {{SIZE}}{{UNIT}};',
    ],
  ]
);

$this->add_responsive_control(
  'Obj-PosXTablet',
  [
    'label' => __( 'Horizontal change', 'plugin-domain' ),
    'type' => Controls_Manager::SLIDER,                
    'devices' => ['tablet'],               
    'range' => [                  
      'min' => -100, 
      'max' => 100,  
      'step'=> 1 ,                      
    ],                    

    'default' => [
      'unit' => '%',
      'size' => 0,
    ],
    'selectors' => [                  
      '(tablet){{WRAPPER}} .theImage' => 'left: {{SIZE}}{{UNIT}};',
    ],
  ]
);
```

by add separate controls and also add the specific devices for each mode you can do what you want , otherwise also by adding (device_mode) before each selectors you can handle the css query media properties

refer to [my answer about responsive selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71826375/elementor-addon-getting-responsive-value-from-another-control-in-selectors-prope)